# Can I cause a Google web search to take a long time?

Tags: google-search

Doing a Google search is normally very fast, despite the fact that the web has probably millions of terabytes of data, due to the fact that Google employs algorithms (like indexing) which allow for very fast searching.

Is it possible to do a search that will cause Google to take much longer than normal (say, a couple of seconds)? I am thinking for example, of using a search term that is obscure and contains various operators, so that it wouldn't be searchable by index. Is there such term?

Comment: just search by typing garbage of letter :P .. like `sandkask das asdka sdna dn` :P Google returns the results instantly no matter what you try to do because indexing is O(1) and is very efficient if the result is not found it returns `Your search - andkask das asdka sdna dn - did not match any documents.`

Comment: yes, but there should be some query that do have result but is probably not possible find from index. For example by using - or quote operator

Comment: In which real case a user would like such thing?

Answer (score 2):

I think the assumption here is that Google can find webpage content that isn't indexed. However, Google will only return results for indexed pages. Therefore, I don't think it's possible to create a search that would take a couple seconds. If a keyword search isn't found in the index, it would simply return as a "there are no results" page.

If anything, I think running a search against a term that is *commonly* found would take longer, since it needs to run through all searches, and return each page and highlight the occurrence of the keyword. That's total conjecture on my part though.